# ReferenceError: document is not defined when using ReactQuill

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, quill

i'm getting start with both next.js and ReactQuill. But when i went run `yarn build`, this is what I get:

```
 info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types
- info Collecting page data ..ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:7661:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:36:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:1030:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:36:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:5655:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:36:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:10045:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:36:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:11557:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.js:36:30)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /Articles
    at C:\Users\joao\Desktop\liceu\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1152:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How am I supposed to use that? I installed the packages, create the file under the `pages` folder. The file goes like this:

```
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';


export default function Articles() {

    const [content, setContent] = useState<ReactQuill.Value>('');

    const handleChange = (value: ReactQuill.Value) => {
      setContent(value);
    };

    return (
      <ReactQuill theme="snow" />
    );
  }
```

What am I imissing? How do I fix that?

Comment: Please, add useIsMounted hook and render ReactQuill only after mount; https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted

Comment: @lluchkaa managed to make it work with `dynamic`. is this better practice than just us IsMouted?

Comment: Yeah, probably that should also work

Comment: or add 'use client' directive if you are using latest nextjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic`. Please, see [this example](https://dev.to/a7u/reactquill-with-nextjs-478b)

Looks like ReactQuill runs only on browser. You can render this element only on client side. I'm not sure what version of Next.js do you use.
You may add `useIsMounted` hook:

```
function useIsMounted() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  return useCallback(() => isMounted.current, [])
}
```

[Link to example](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted)

Then you it like this:

```
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Articles() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<ReactQuill.Value>('')
  const isMounted = useIsMounted()

  const handleChange = (value: ReactQuill.Value) => {
    setContent(value)
  }

  return isMounted() ? <ReactQuill theme="snow" /> : null
}
```